# How to properly show image stored from a remote file server to a django HTML template?

Tags: python, django

I have trouble displaying images stored in a file server to the django template.
File server link is \11234.123.123.123\dashboard.jpg (just a sample).
It seems like the img src url is being added by the django localhost url prefix to the file server path as follows: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/\\11234.123.123.123\dashboard.jpg`

In django template, the img tag is written as:
`<img class="imgView" src="{{dashboard_image}}" alt="Dashboard画面.jpg"></img>`

My views.py just sends the image file server URL as text (with value of \11234.123.123.123\dashboard.jpg) to be displayed as image in the HTML page as the django template.

```
def dashboard(request):
    dashboard_image_url = '\\11234.123.123.123\dashboard.jpg' #TODO temporary, just sample
    context = {'dashboard_image': dashboard_image_url}
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', context)
```

But, the image does not show properly as follows. [image: img error]

Please help, thank you!

Comment: What is the variable `dashboard_image`? Please show the view for this template and any relevant model.

Comment: Hi @AbdulAzizBarkat, I updated my query and added the snippets for views.py. I did not use a model for this one since I do not need to store the URL to the database.

Comment: Firstly `11234.123.123.123` does not appear to be a valid IP address. Are you sure you have the correct url? Next urls use front slashes instead of back slashes. So instead of `\\11234.123.123.123\dashboard.jpg` it should be `//11234.123.123.123/dashboard.jpg`. Also `\ ` is an escape character...

Comment: Hi @AbdulAzizBarkat, `11234.123.123.123` is a sample non-existent IP address, I intentionally changed it here. I changed using backslash (\)  to a slash (/), but it accesses the file server address as an http URL by adding `http:` as prefix and page is still not able to show the image.

Comment: When we write `//` in a url it means use the same protocol as the current one (for you the current protocol is `http`) so if you want to use `https` you should specify it in the url: `https://11234.123.123.123/dashboard.jpg`.

Comment: Hi @AbdulAzizBarkat, adding 'http' or 'https' does not solve the problem. If I check the console logs in the browser, I am getting an error message: `Not allowed to load local resource: file://11234.123.123.123/dashboard.jpg`. If I don't use django and directly load the HTML page by itself with this tag: `<img class="imgView" src="\\11234.123.123.123\dashboard.jpg"></img>` then the image just displays. But, I have to use django and make this work on django.

Comment: By any chance is this IP your local IP address...?

Comment: No, it is another remote server IP address.

Answer (score 0):

In your template instead of:

```html
<img class="imgView" src="{{dashboard_image}}" alt="Dashboard画面.jpg"></img>
```

DO this:

```html
<img class="imgView" src="{{dashboard_image.url}}" alt="Dashboard画面.jpg"></img>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I tried but it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
<img class='img-responsive' src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ item.image.url }}" />
or
<img class='img-responsive' src="{{ item.image.url }}" />

and in main urls.py

from django.conf import settings 
from django.conf.urls.static import static 


urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: How do you add the URL configuration for a file server url that can only be accessed by IP address within the same network where the django page will be served?